# Translation into Mexican Spanish of Customer Information

Tags: traducción, expresiones, méxico

I've generated a Spanish translation for these two sentences, but they don't quite sound right to me. I'd like some feedback!

Have a question or concern about your device? We’re here to help! = **Pregunta o preocupación acerca de su dispositivo? ¡Podemos ayudar!**

Before returning your device, visit [URL] or call Technical Support. = **Antes de devolver tu dispositivo, visite [URL] o llame al soporte técnico.**

Please advise! I don't want the text to sound too robotic or formal. How would this sound in conversational Mexican Spanish?

Comment: Note that you are mixing 2nd persons: _tu dispositivo_ (informal) does not match _visite_ or _llame [usted]_ (formal). I'm not Mexican, but it seems that your target fits better a _tu_ (_visita/llama_)

Answer (score 1):

I find the translation of the second sentence to be fine.

However, the first one does not sound natural to me. I'd revise it as follows:

- ¿Alguna pregunta/duda o inquietud acerca de su dispositivo? ¡Estamos aquí para ayudarlo! (o: ¡Estamos aquí para asistirlo!)

Some speakers might prefer to fuse the question and the exclamation following it into a single sentence as follows:

- En caso de cualquier pregunta/duda o inquietud / Si tiene cualquier pregunta/duda o inquietud acerca de su dispositivo, estamos aquí para ayudarlo/asistirlo.

Note: The slanted bars offer different options for you to choose from.